# LoggingOutInterceptor to a string in java

Tags: java, cxf

i have a logging like this:

```
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(test);
    client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
    client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
```

to capture a soap request and response. It is printing perfectly output to a console. But I want to capture that output to a string so I can use it in other parts of the program. So is there anyway to capture this to a string instead of console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that extends `AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message>`. You can do whatever you want with the soap message there.

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;

public class CustomOutInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {


    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        //do something with your message here
    }
    public CustomOutInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.POST_LOGICAL);
    }
}
```

Message object contains your soap message. You can process it any way you want.
So in your code you'd have to go for:

```
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(test);
    client.getOutInterceptors().add(new CustomOutInterceptor());
```

Comment: Can you please give some example? I am very new to this